# MS word template wont save add-in as active

Tags: ms-word

I have one file with macros (file type is word macro-enabled template .dotm), same file also has a ribbon modification (a button in custom tab, which calls macros in same file).

Macros are very simple - just insert static text in current document.

I have a different file (same type .dotm) where I include first file through "Developer->Add-Ins". As a result I have a new ribbon tab with a button. If I press the button I have text in document - everything works. Until I save/load file. It never saves included add-in state, this add-in is always inactive (if I activate it manually it works).

If I put the template file into the Word startup folder it loads but I do not want to load it for all documents, just for that one.

I tried enable all macros, sign first file - nothing works. That add-in is unchecked (you can see it in list, but it is marked as inactive).
(Show add-in user interface errors - does not show anything).

Why won't Word save included add-in as active and how to make it to save add-in as active?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can not load template/add-in for only single document.
You can load add-in for session or put it to startup folder to load it for each document.